# OpenVAS HTML Report

Tags: report, openvas

Based on the [how to](https://www.linuxincluded.com/installing-openvas-on-centos-7/) i've installed a fresh test vm with openvas with CentOS. It seems to work well and i can create an PDF export after a scan. But there is no export format for HTML. I've exported then the report format from a  appliance and import this on my vm. But if i select HTML on "download filtered report" und try to make a report, i see an empty error message and i can only click close.

I've checked the logs but i don't find helpful entrys. Maybe someone have an idea? Or are HTML exports on the self-managed OpenVAS not available?

Answer (score 2):

It's often better to ask such questions at https://community.greenbone.net/ directly to get faster feedback.

Nevertheless the a HTML report isn't included in GVM 10 anymore. A new customizable HTML report will only be available for Greenbone customers.